# 'ModuleNotFoundError' in Python 3.x

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am using Python 3.8.3. I have set up a virtual environment using [pipenv](https://pypi.org/project/pipenv/).
I have installed following Python Packages

- [translate](https://pypi.org/project/translate/)
- [googletrans](https://pypi.org/project/googletrans/)
- [pyjokes](https://pypi.org/project/pyjokes/)

using the following commands

- `pipenv install translate`
- `pipenv install googletrans`
- `pipenv install pyjokes`

I can see these packages in **Pipfile** and **Pipefile.lock** files

[image]

[image]

and my code is as follow

```
import pyjokes
from translate import Translator

try:

    input_content = pyjokes.get_joke()
    translator = Translator(to_lang="ja")
    output_content = translator.translate(input_content)

    print(output_content)

except Exception as ex:
    print(ex)
```

But when I run this I get the following **ERROR**

[image]

I got the same kind of error while using **googletrans**. If I install both **translate** and **googletrans** using `pip install` command then everything works fine.

Why few packages are not working which are installed using `pipenv install` command?

Answer (score 0):

Looks Like Your Virtual Environment is not activated
Run this Command to activate the shell

```
pipenv shell
```

If this won't work then you have to run the code manually by typing the command don't use the run button to execute the file

```
python filename.py
```

Comment: When I run pipenv shell command then nothing happend. Terminal showed the following messgae 'Launching subshell in virtual environment…
Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Try the new cross-platform PowerShell https://aka.ms/pscore6'

Comment: When I run py filename.py command in powershell, it gave the same error module not found.

Answer (score 0):

`pipenv` by default creates a virtual environment at '**c:\users\username\.virtualenvs\**' in windows.

If a virtual environment is created at the above-mentioned location and packages are installed at that location then **some packages won't work** as shown in the question. So need to create a virtual environment in the project folder.

To create a virtual environment in a project folder

- Create **.venv** folder inside the project folder
- Now create a virtual environment using `pipenv --three` command. `pipenv` will now create a virtual environment at '**ProjectFolder\.venv**' location instead of default location '**c:\users\username\.virtualenvs\**'
- Now install packages using `pipenv install` command and everything will work fine.

There will be no more '**ModuleNotFoundError**'.